# How to make IIS to deliver stylesheets with the correct MIME type?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, http-headers, mime

Currently my IIS is serving CSS files with no Content-Type header.
How to change it?

Should I change it on my application or in the server?

Comment: That should be default behavior on IIS since IIS5: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitly an IIS/OS function and should be set in IIS.

How to add it depends on the version of IIS you are using...

Here are instructions for [IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true) and [IIS 7.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: The default setting in IIS 7 is to add "Content-type:text/css" to .css files. But it is not working.

Comment: I think I should submit a bug report to Microsoft.